# How can I add a script function to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-helmet

I am trying to add an external application Chameleon onto my react application and for that I have to add the [javascript function](https://help.trychameleon.com/setup-installation-and-account/installing-chameleon/installing-directly-with-javascript) to my application.

I only want it to be called in specific situations so I don't want to load it in my `index.html`. I tried adding it to the `render` function of my component as:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
     <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">/* Chameleon - better user onboarding */!function(t,n,o){var a="chmln",c="setup identify alias track clear set show on off custom help _data".split(" ");n[a]||(n[a]={}),n[a].accountToken=o,n[a].location=n.location.href.toString();for(var e=0;e<c.length;e++)!function(){var t=n[a][c[e]+"_a"]=[];n[a][c[e]]=function(){t.push(arguments)}}();var s=t.createElement("script");s.src="https://fast.trychameleon.com/messo/"+o+"/messo.min.js",s.async=!0,t.head.appendChild(s)}(document,window,"TOKEN");
         chmln.identify(USER.ID_IN_DB, {     // Unique ID of each user in your database (e.g. 23443 or "590b80e5f433ea81b96c9bf6")
            email: USER.EMAIL });
      </script>
      ...
      ...
     </head>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But the above doesn't seem to work. I tried the same inside a helmet but no luck. Both of them show an error for

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

Is there a way I can load this function in a specific component or do I have to do it in the `index.html`?

Comment: you import it in javascript using `import ./path/to/your/file.js`

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii as part of calling the function I need to send the current users id and name which I would have access to in the component because of the state value but I won't have access to it in the javascript file

Comment: @IsaacVidrine unfortunately neither of them are available otherwise I would prefer that method as well. The only way to add this third party app to the existing React app is using the function I showed above and added a link to so I am trying to do it through that flow

Comment: What do you mean neither of them are available? If it isnt a node module place your code in a file and import it.

Comment: https://help.trychameleon.com/setup-installation-and-account/installing-chameleon/installing-for-different-js-frameworks

Comment: @IsaacVidrine no, it's not. Chameleon requires a code snippet generated via the UI.

Comment: @djfdev ahh, gotcha.. must be a different library with the same name then

Comment: I ended up adding the javascript function in the index because it looked like there was no other way to do it and I am just accessing it using `window` as @djfdev link detailed

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want the code snippet to load on every page? This seems like an edge case.

Comment: Did you mean you don't want to call `chmln.identify` on every page? If that is the case, then simply break up the code you provided. The snippet should be loaded in a script tag in index.html, and the function can be called from anywhere within the React application.

Comment: I didn’t want the code snippet to load on every page. I have a publicly available section to the same app where I don’t need it and I was hoping to only call it when a user visits their dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a strong misunderstanding of what react is for and how it is used.

1) There should only ever be 1 `head` element on the page, and it should be in `index.html` not in the rendered output of a component.

2) Having a component render a `<script>` tag goes against the point of using react.

What you need to do is `import` the code you need into your component:

`import './path/to/file.js'`

And then from there `chmln` should be available on the `window` object

```
window.chmln.identify()
```

Comment: This answer is a bit misguided. Chameleon is a service that uses a code snippet for reporting metrics from your web application. The correct way to install it is by using a script tag in the head of your HTML file.

Comment: @djfdev If there is one thing I know for a fact about programming, its that there is almost never only 1 correct way of doing something. Sure, you could add `script` in index.html, but OP said they didn't want to load it in every page. I've updated my answer after doing a little more research on chameleon.